# server_internal_error on MOVE and DELETE?

Tags: onedrive

We have noticed today that we are getting server_internal_error on MOVE and DELETE.  The same code works in the past.  Is this a temporary issue on the server side, or is there a recent API change that is causing this?

The problem occurs regardless of the client platform.  In fact, we are able to reproduce it using the APIExplorer sample code from the Windows version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the service that has since been resolved.

When encountering trouble with the service you can speed up responsiveness by include request/response details.

Comment: Yes.  This is to confirm that the problem is indeed resolved from yesterday.