# 500 errors all of a sudden when deleting a folder from REST API in ONEDRive

Tags: onedrive

I have a program that uses the OneDrive LiveAPI REST api to a bunch of file operations.

It runs every night. Last night and up to right now, the Delete command for deleting a folder is failing with a 500 error.

Request and response is below. Anyone know why this just started happening. This same code has been running fine for months. All the other REST commands seem to be fine.

```html
DELETE https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.27bddd375ac4fd5c.27BDDD375AC4FD5C!13479?access_token=<VALID TOKEN> HTTP/1.1
Host: apis.live.net

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 145
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: Live-API/19.15.216.5001 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
X-MSNSERVER: CH3301____PAP154
X-QosStats: {"ApiId":2501025,"ResultType":3,"SourcePropertyId":25,"TargetPropertyId":0}
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-HTTP-Live-Request-Id: API.d9fbbf18-a7cb-43ce-a07c-95b14040ab0f
X-AsmVersion: UNKNOWN; 19.15.0.0
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2015 18:56:48 GMT

{
   "error": {
      "code": "server_internal_error", 
      "message": "An error occurred while performing the action. Try again later."
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an service issue that impacted this aspect of Live Connect, so if your code was working correctly previously then that's most likely the cause. The issue should now be resolved.

Comment: Indeed its all just working again today. Thanks. Didn't see a service outage on the one drive page at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting the same error from yesterday as well.  It happens on DELETE and MOVE.  Other commands seem to work okay.

[server_internal_error on MOVE and DELETE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833859/server-internal-error-on-move-and-delete)

It's probably an internal error at the server side.  Let's hope OneDrive team will fix it soon.